# Overflow hidden on bottom of image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im trying to **hide** the bottom of the girl image when the 3D background is triggered. I tried to add the `overflow: hidden;` to the `test-imgplace` class and it doesn't look right.

Is there a better way to fix it?

See what I did on **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/p4egsvb6/49/)**

```css
.card .image {
  height: 275px;
  width: 183px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.imgtest {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.test-imgplace {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .text {
  height: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card {
  width: 183px;
  height: 275px;
  margin: auto auto;
  background: #383030;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-content {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.hover-in {
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.hover-out {
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.card-hover {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-imgplace">
  <img src="https://christianluneborg.com/imgs/test-woman.png" class="imgtest">
  <div class="card-hover">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://christianluneborg.com/imgs/test-woman-bg.png);"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `background-size` on the image, have you tried the `object-fit` property?

Comment: In what way does `overflow: hidden;` on the `test-imgplace` class not look right?

Comment: @SpyderScript - https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/p4egsvb6/17/ - I added the `overflow: hidden; and you can see it doesn't look right. I just want the bottom of the girl image to hide.

Comment: @NicolasGoosen - No, Im not sure if that will work.

Comment: Try adding this to `.imgtest`: `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% calc(100% - 22px), 0% calc(100% - 22px));`

Comment: Full disclosure: your script is way over my head so I'm not even going to attempt to jump into it but I have a theory and you might know how to implement it: what if you added another card that strictly has a white outline (or whatever background color you'll have this against) and make it so that it follows the card behind her but is actually layered over both her and the background card? That way the outline would essentially hide the overflow provided the container is big enough to allow that. I tried doing it myself but like I said your code is definitely beyond my knowledge. Good luck! :)

Comment: @SpyderScript - https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/p4egsvb6/20/ Im not sure if it was updated on the girl image. Its not doing anything. Could you use the JSFiddle and edit it from there? Would that help?

Comment: @AStombaugh - appreciate it for trying!

Comment: It did update for me, the bottom of the girl's dress is no longer visible below the background, at least while the image is not hovered over. If you want the dress to be clipped according to the background even **while** the image is being hovered, I would try something like what @AStombaugh suggested.

Comment: The problem is that your girl image is _outside_ of the `.card` element that has `overflow: hidden;` set.

Comment: It works if you move your `<img>` tag to immediately inside the `div.card` element (at the top of it). But then the girl also transforms. You might be able to somehow reverse her transform so it looks like she's standing still?